# How to compute ElGamal decryption by hand

Tags: elgamal-encryption, number-theory, elgamal-signature

Lets say that $u=3, x=5, v=2$, how do we work out $u^{-x}*v$, so $3^{-5} * 2$. I know how to work out the answer if it was $3^5 * 2$ but how do we do it with negative exponents?

Comment: I added some formatting to your post - Please ensure I did not change the meaning (I had to assume the precedence for u^-x * v was $u^{-x} * v$ and not $u^{-x * v}$)

Answer (score 2):

We're not trying to compute $3^{-5}\ast 2$, but instead we're trying to compute $3^{-5}\ast 2\mod p$ for some prime $p$.
This is notation for $(3^{-1})^5\ast 2\mod p$, so if we can compute what $3^{-1}\mod p$ is, you can just plug that value in and do computations like you'd expect.
Note that $3^{-1}\mod p$ means the element $u\in(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ such that $u\ast 3\equiv 1\mod p$.
For example, because $2\ast 2\mod 3 \equiv 1\mod 3$, we have that $2^{-1} \mod 3= 2$.
Or, because $2\ast 3\equiv 1\mod 5$, we have that $2^{-1}\mod 5\equiv 3$.
The quantity $u^{-1}$ ends up being uniquely defined (when it exists --- $2\ast 3\equiv 0\mod 6$ means that $2^{-1}\mod 6$ can't exist), but note that it depends on both $u$ *and* $p$.

A computationally inefficient (but conceptually simple) way to compute $3^{-1}$ is via [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), which states that:

> If $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $a^p\equiv a\mod p$

If $a\neq 0$, this is equivalent to $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$, and therefore $a^{p-2}\equiv a^{-1}\mod p$.
So we can compute $3^{-1}\mod p\equiv 3^{p-2}\mod p$, which you can do by hand.
If $p$ is large this might be annoying, but there are some tricks to speed it up (known as [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)).

A more computationally efficient way to compute this quantity is the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). This requires more explanation though, and if you want to know more about it you can probably find some resources online explaining it (it's a standard topic in elementary number theory courses).